# Insert after an element - logic help

Tags: jquery, append

I have the following:

```
$.post(baseUrl+"/index/voto",{id:eid},function(e){
 var divMsg = $("#msg");
 var html = "";
   if(e.msg == 1){
     html = '<img src="'+baseUrl+'/lib/img/showImageA.png" alt="pdf" />';
   }else if(e.msg == 3){
     //HERE I MUST DISPLAY A TEXT AFTER A GIVEN ELEMENT
   } else if(e.msg == 2){
     html = '<img src="'+baseUrl+'/lib/img/showImageB.png" alt="pdf" />';
   } else{
     html = '<img src="'+baseUrl+'/lib/img/showImageC.png" alt="pdf" />';
   }
   divMsg.show();
   divMsg.html(html); 

}, 'json');
```

So, if something arrives, I will replace the content with an image. 
This works.

The issue is that, on the second case `(e.msg ==3)` I should **not** remove or replace the all thing with an image, **but** I need to append an element p on a specific place saying: "something".

I tried to display:none; that element and then add:

```
else if(e.msg == 3){
 myParagrafId.show();
}
```

Nothing appears.

I tried to:

```
else if(e.msg == 3){
 $('#foo').append('<p>Something</p>');
}
```

Still nothing...

The function seems to be returning the html, ignoring my instructions inside the second conditional.

So, perhaps I need to grab the existing html part, append what I need, and then allow the function to output it ?

**Additional note:**
If I place an alert(); inside that condition (e.msg == 3) it works.

Comment: You can use after method to put any markup or dom element.

Comment: If e.msg is not 3 then it will not do anything that you write inside that if block. May be you should see why its not returning 3 as expected.

Comment: Does it definitely enter the `else if(e.msg == 3)` block? Try just putting an alert in there and see if it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First af all you are always putting `html` into `$("#msg")` here

```
//in case 3 html = ''
divMsg.html(html);
```

so you should check it's not an empty string:

```
if (html != ''){
    divMsg.html(html);
}
```

So if you were trying to do somenthing inside `$("#msg")` (like showing an hidden div inside it) in case 3 it does nothing because it gets replaced by '' because you are calling `$("#msg").html('');`

does this help?

Otherwise you are doing something wrong in that if, if you show your markup we can help

Comment: Indeed that helped... I believe I was removing a parent element with display:none; :s - arrhh!!! dummy,.... checking now... Yup. I was removing a parent element, and an append after an element that was not considered, doesn't work. Solved. Thanks Nicola. :DDD

Comment: If I use $('#foo').append('<p>Something</p>');
 and #foo is an anchor id, I notice that instead of having: <a id="foo">foo</a><p>something</p>, I GET <a id="foo">foo <p>something</p></a> Is this the expected behaviour ?

Comment: Indeed the after() was what I should look at. :)

Comment: @MEM ies it's after() what you needed! :)